# How to copy a cell from one spreadsheet to another based on criteria in the target sheet

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement, copy

I have two spreadsheets, 1st with case related info (patient info, address, etc) 2nd with hospital info (address, etc). I would like to copy the hospital ID from the hospital spreadsheet to the case spreadsheet where the hospital id city is the same as the case id city.

Example

Case
Patient 2, New York, etc

Hospital
Hospital 1, New York, etc

New Case
Patient 2, New York, Hospital 1

Goal is to take the hospital ID from hospital.xls and copy it to case_details where the city matches between hospital and case.
[image: CASE IMAGE]

[image: HOSPITAL]

Comment: how is your data arrange exactly? in once cell or in one row but different columns? can you elaborate on the example data?

Comment: Very unclear, but I'm thinking... have you tried `VLOOKUP`? Is it not enough in this case?

Comment: here `=IFERROR(Index('[Hospitals.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$1:$E$3,MATCH($H2,'[Hospitals.xlsx]Sheet1'!$E$1:$E$3,0),-4),"")`. Put formula in `P2` in `Case` workbook. Change the sheet name and ranges to suit.

Comment: Dropped the 2nd workbook and created another sheet - using the following formula nothing gets entered into P2 in sheet1 - =IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!$A$1:$E$3,MATCH(B2,Sheet2!$E$1:$E$3,0),-4),"")

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a layout as in the image, please try in Sheet1 C2:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!A:A,MATCH(B2,Sheet2!B:B,0)),"")
```

and copy down to suit.

[image: SO21152173 example]

Comment: think this is pretty close to my goal - added screenshots to help define the issue

Comment: I tried the following but nothing gets put in cell P1 using the following formula - =IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!$A$1:$E$3,MATCH(B2,Sheet2!$E$1:$E$3,0),-4),"")

Comment: Also dropped the different workbooks and now have one workbook with sheet1 being case and sheet2 being hospitals

Comment: That did it - I see what it was now - perfect!